# Open Attachment from within List Field in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I'm using the below code to populate the list of attachments for each item in a SharePoint Online list. Works good but the hyperlink doesn't open the attachment, as is desired. Can I add an onClick event or similar to open the corresponding attachment in a new window?

[image]

```
(function () { 
  var fieldContext = {}; 
  fieldContext.Templates = {}; 
  fieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
    "CommentAtt": { "View": attFieldTemplate }, 
  }; 

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext); 

})(); 

function attFieldTemplate(ctx) { 
  var myComm = ctx.CurrentItem["ID"];
  return getProjCommAttachments(myComm);
} 

function getProjCommAttachments(myComm) {
  var endpointUrl = "mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items(" + myComm + ")/AttachmentFiles";
  var myAttachments = "";

  getJson(endpointUrl)
  .done(function(data) {
    var items = data.d.results;
    $.each(items, function(i) {
      myAttachments += "<div><a href=" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + ">" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a></div>";
    });
  })

  return myAttachments;
}

function getJson(url) {
  return $.ajax({ 
    async: false,      
    url: url,   
    type: "GET",  
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
  });
}   // getJson
```

Comment: what kind of field is CommentAtt?

Comment: "Multiple lines of text"

Comment: what happen if you change the type to hyperlink?

Comment: What happened when you click on attachment link?

Comment: @Marco same behavior if the column is changed to type "hyperlink." When I click on the link I get the "edit" icon

Comment: @VirajGorajia When I click on the link I get the "edit" icon and the hyperlinked page does not open. I think this is because I'm in "Quick Edit" mode. I think an OnClick event to recreate hyperlink functionality will be required.

Answer (score 3):

Update line with below code:

```
myAttachments += "<div><a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a></div>";
```

Comment: Same behavior with this update: I get an edit cursor icon and the hyperlinked pages does not open